# FileNotFoundError in subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

I want to connect and use the functions of adb in a python environment.
In the terminal, adb is connected well as shown below.

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133
Installed as /opt/homebrew/bin/adb

$ command -v adb
/opt/homebrew/bin/adb
```

To use this in the python environment, subprocess.check_output was used,
I wrote python code as below.

```
import subprocess

cmd = f"adb --version"
print(f"cmd:{cmd}")
res = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
print(f"res:{res}")
```

I got an error as below.

```
$ python test.py
cmd:adb --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hhd/project/hhdpy/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    res = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/hhdpy/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/hhdpy/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/hhdpy/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/hhdpy/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adb --version'
```

In my opinion, subprocess.check_output does not seem to be able to import the PATH environment variable,
How should I solve it?

Comment: It's treating `--version` as part of the literal command name.  Presumably you meant the command to be just `adb`, with an _argument_ of `--version`.

Comment: @Hyundong Hwang does the answer below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by John, one possible solution would be to provide `--version` as an argument.

To do so, you have to split the `cmd` command into a list, for instance:

```
res = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "--version"]).decode("utf-8")
```

tested with Python3.

Comment: You do `subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(' ')).decode("utf-8")` to automate the list form easily